# XSD: Allowing different elements inside an element only after the first appearance of that element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an question about XSD. Is it possible to allow different elements inside an element, if the element already appeared?

Lets say I have this structure:

```
<entry>
    <col>
        <b></b>
    </col>
    <col>
        <a></a>
        <b></b>
    </col>
</entry>
```

```
  <xs:element name="col">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="a" />
        <xs:element ref="b" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

At the moment the `<a>` element can be set every time. But I only want to allow an `<a>` element to be set, if the `<col>` element appeared atleast once before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

Create a variable for counting number of `<col>`

```
<xsl:variable name="colCount" select="count(/entry/col)" />
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="colCount" select="count(//col)" />
```

Then check if number of `<col>` is at least 1. If yes, `<a>` will be added.

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsl:if test="$colCount &gt; 0">
        <xs:element ref="a" />
    </xsl:if>
    ...
```